# Click on web browser link label using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, click

This is code that I want to click:

```
<span class="label-pedido" id="label-pedido-20489948">Exibir</span>
```

"20489948" changes all the time.

I've tried using this code:

```
 For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("label-pedido")

                    Element.OuterHtml.Contains("Exibir")

                    Element.InvokeMember("click")
```

with no success.

What code can I do to click this?

Answer (score 1):

GetElementsbByTagName is used to get all elements with given tag name like Table, B, TD etc.. in the code you posted the tag name of element is SPAN

> ```
>    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
>
>         If Element.GetAttribute("class") = "label-pedido" And Element.OuterHtml.Contains("Exibir")Then
>             Element.InvokeMember("click")
>         End If
>
>     Next
> ```

In the above code if  there is more than one span tags with class "label-pedido" then all this will get clicked which has text 'Exibir'. But if you want to click only the specific element it is better to use GetElementbyID method. But as you said this cannot be used if ID is always changing.

Comment: is not only one span :/

Comment: so if there is only one span with text 'Exibir', then the above code will do or  else something unique about the span should be added to condition